# Cannot find name 'HammerManager'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-material

I am using 
@angular-2.0.0-rc.5, 
@angular2-material 2.0.0-alpha.7-4 &
Angular-CLI 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2

When I try to compile it throws an error, Cannot find name 'HammerManager'. Please see attached screenshot.

[image: Errors]

I found some solution for Angular-CLI (non-webpack) version but none for webpack version with.

Any one got this fixed with above setup ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me ...

1. npm install hammerjs --save-dev
2. npm install @types/hammerjs --save-dev
3. import 'hammerjs'; (in main.ts)

Thanks to @j2L4e & this answer https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/issues/244#issuecomment-241600752

Comment: i was facing similar issue so I followed your 3 steps but on browser console I am getting error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3002/hammerjs` Do I need to add anything in systemjs.config.js or index.html?

Answer (score 12):

You'll need to install the missing typings:

```
npm install @types/hammerjs --save-dev
```

Then put a reference to the hammerjs typings into your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"types": [
  ...,
  "hammerjs"
]
```

if that's not enough, also install hammerjs itself via npm:

```
npm i hammerjs
```

Comment: its not working ... still same problem ... I did npm install hammerjs --save-dev & added reference in tsconfig.json as @j2L4e mentioned

Comment: `npm install @types/jammerjs --save-dev`

Comment: typo. its `@types/hammerjs` obviously.

Comment: did you `npm install hammerjs` too?

Comment: whats your projects typescript version? run `node_modules/.bin/tsc -v`

Comment: yes I did. only part extra i did as mentioned in my answer import 'hammerjs'; in main.ts

Comment: I see you got it working. No idea why you'd need to `import 'hammerjs'`, but glad it works. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

While you should use --save-dev when installing the typings, you should use --save when installing hammerjs itself. You will want that installed in production.

Comment: Depends on what you are doing. If you are creating a library that can optionally make use of hammerjs (eg. optional inclusion of gesture support), then you want to develop the library with hammerjs by installing hammer via `devDependencies` and also declare it in `optionalDependencies` in order to give a hint to the library's consumers.